# React Stateless component broken after npm update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Im coming back to programming after 4 months, so i deciding to npm update this project but it broke on all my stateless functions.

```
interface INotFoundPageContainerProps {
    history: any;
}

class NotFoundPageContainer extends React.Component<INotFoundPageContainerProps, any> {

    constructor(props: INotFoundPageContainerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.onClickHomeButton = this.onClickHomeButton.bind(this);
    }

    onClickHomeButton(): void {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NotFoundPage
                onClickHomeButton={this.onClickHomeButton}
            />
        );
    }

}

export default withRouter(NotFoundPageContainer);
```

Error:

TS gives me an error on the last line of the above code:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof NotFoundPageContainer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>>'.
  Type 'typeof NotFoundPageContainer' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>>'.
    Type 'typeof NotFoundPageContainer' provides no match for the signature '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any> & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any>'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The React.Component's properties type is incorrect, because you're wrapping it in withRouter HOC.**

---

The component `<NotFoundPageContainer/>` is being wrapped by `withRouter`, which passes down router-specific properties, but you don't reflect that in `NotFoundPageContainer`'s type definition.

Consider something like that instead

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

interface INotFoundPageContainerRouterProps {
    history: any;
}

interface INotFoundPageContainerProps 
  extends RouteComponentProps<INotFoundPageContainerRouterProps> {

}
```

and then you're ready to define your component's type properly

```
class NotFoundPageContainer 
  extends React.Component<INotFoundPageContainerProps, any> { ... }
```

Comment: Ahh i understand now. Much appreciated! For anyone curious it was the React Router update that broke the code.